# kvc get subview lastobject

Tags: ios, subview, kvc

I have a problem.
first,I have a NSArray like this:

```
(NSMutableArray *)currentCanMoveAndDeleteCellArray {
        NSInteger count = [self.contentCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];
        NSMutableArray *currentCells = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
        for (int index = 0 ; index < count; ++index) {
            UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.contentCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
            if(cell) {
                [currentCells addObject:[self.contentCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]]];
            }
        }
        return currentCells;
    }
```

then I want to get their last subviews, I use `kvc get subviews` like this.

```
[self.currentCanMoveAndDeleteCellArray valueForKeyPath:@"subviews"]
```

and I got:

```
    <__NSArrayI 0x1710793c0>(
    <__NSArrayM 0x17405a670>(
    <UIView: 0x155de9020; frame = (0 0; 80 30); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x170248f40>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1702363a0>>,
    <UILabel: 0x155e524d0; frame = (70 -10; 20 20); clipsToBounds = YES; tag = 123; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17405a520>; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x17409f540>>
    )
,
 <__NSArrayM 0x17405cf80>(
    <UIView: 0x155e7cbf0; frame = (0 0; 80 30); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17405d3a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x174431a40>>,
    <UILabel: 0x155e7ceb0; frame = (70 -10; 20 20); clipsToBounds = YES; tag = 123; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17405d400>; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x17409f9a0>>
    )
        ,
 <__NSArrayM 0x17405f6b0>(
    <UIView: 0x155e7da80; frame = (0 0; 80 30); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17405faa0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x174433440>>,
    <UILabel: 0x155e7dd40; frame = (70 -10; 20 20); clipsToBounds = YES; tag = 123; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17405fb00>; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x174282f30>>
    )
<__NSArrayM 0x174240990>(
<UIView: 0x155e7e150; frame = (0 0; 80 30); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x174240d80>; layer = <CALayer: 0x174433e60>>,
<UILabel: 0x155e7e410; frame = (70 -10; 20 20); clipsToBounds = YES; tag = 123; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x174240de0>; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x174283610>>
)
,
    <__NSArrayM 0x174241c50>(
    <UIView: 0x155e7ec30; frame = (0 0; 80 30); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x174242040>; layer = <CALayer: 0x174434880>>,
    <UILabel: 0x155e7eef0; frame = (70 -10; 20 20); clipsToBounds = YES; tag = 123; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1742420a0>; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x174283cf0>>
    )
,
<__NSArrayM 0x174242f10>(
<UIView: 0x155e7f710; frame = (0 0; 80 30); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x174243300>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1744352a0>>,
<UILabel: 0x155e7f9d0; frame = (70 -10; 20 20); clipsToBounds = YES; tag = 123; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x174243360>; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x1742843d0>>
)
)
```

who can tell me how to got last subview.

I tried to write:
 `[self.currentCanMoveAndDeleteCellArray valueForKeyPath:@"subviews.@lastObject"]`

but, you know that it isn't result that i want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UICollectionViewCell class in array.
After, you can get subview.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)currentCanMoveAndDeleteCellArray {
    NSInteger count = [self.contentCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];
    self.currentCells = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];

    for (int index = 0 ; index < count; ++index) {

        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.contentCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];

        if(cell) {

            [ self.currentCells addObject:cell]; }

    } return  self.currentCells;

}
-(void)getCell{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [ self.currentCells objectAtIndex:_index];

    for (UIView * view in [cell subviews]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",view);
    }
}
```

Comment: will,it works ,but i want use kvc to process,it looks like  pretty.beacuse i had already use it get subviews.